# Using camlidl for interface with opaque struct

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to use `camlidl` with a C library to generate OCaml bindings.  This library uses the "opaque struct" method of keeping object state: all functions take or give a pointer to the struct, meaning my code has no visibility into it.  The library's .h file includes something like:

```c
typedef struct opaque_struct opaque_struct;

opaque_struct * create_opaque_struct;
int do_x_with_opaque_struct(int, opaque struct *);
void destroy_opaque_struct(opaque struct *);
```

and so I am expected to never use the struct directly, but instead to use a pointer to it everywhere.

Unfortunately, I can't find in the `camlidl` manual how to do this The Right Way.   I checked these sections:

- 3.5 Structs

  None of this is useful to me - I am dealing with an incomplete struct definition and don't want / can't use any translation to a caml object.
- 3.2 Pointers

  It seems like it should work to always use `[ptr] struct opaque_struct *` everywhere.  But this has a drawback: the `destroy_opaque_struct(opaque_struct * x)` is not called automatically when the object goes out of scope and GC happens.  This forces the OCaml user to manage references themselves.
- 3.8 Type Definitions

  While this would give me `[finalize(destroy_opaque_struct)]` like I wanted for GC, I cannot use a typedef, as it *generates broken code*.  I tried `typedef [abstract] struct opaque_struct opaque_struct` alone.  This generates c2ml and ml2c routines that do not work: they attempt to do a pointer assignment for an incomplete type, which does not work at all.

So what's the proper way to handle this?  This seems like a common enough use case that I imagine camlidl should support it, but I'm missing something.

---

EDIT: Some playing around, and I've found one way to do it.  Consider test.idl containing:

```c
quote(c, "void camlidl_destroy_opaque_struct(opaque_struct * x) { destroy_opaque_struct(x); }");
typedef [abstract,finalize(camlidl_destroy_opaque_struct),ml2c(dummy),c2ml(dummy)] struct opaque_struct opaque_struct;

[ptr] * opaque_struct create_opaque_struct();
int do_x_with_opaque_struct([in] int int_param, [in,ptr] opaque_struct * struct_param);
```

This produces a _stubs.c with "dummy" #define settings for the ml2c and c2ml helpers, like so:

```c
...
void camlidl_destroy_opaque_struct(opaque_struct * x) { 
destroy_opaque_struct(x); }
#define camlidl_ml2c_test_opaque_struct(v,c,ctx) dummy(v,c)

#define camlidl_c2ml_test_opaque_struct(c,ctx) dummy(c)

value camlidl_test_create_opaque_struct(value _unit)
{
  ...
```

Since I never actually use the opaque_struct directly, c2ml and ml2c are never actually called, so it's OK that they are not present.

However, MAN does this seem like a gross way to do it!  I may submit a pull req to add a special-case parameter so that if you tag it **void** (e.g. `c2ml(void)`), it completely omits creating a c2ml or ml2c function.  It still seems like a hack and there should be a better-supported way.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did eventually email Xavier Leroy (the project maintainer) about this, and here is his response.

> I'll try to help you, but as a preface to the reply:
>
> camlidl is an old project that I developed in the late 1990's and
>   haven't touched much since then, except to make sure that it still
>   compiles with recent OCaml versions.  A few projects still use
>   camlidl, at Microsoft in particular, but more recent projects tend to
>   use Ctypes instead (https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes).  I
>   don't recommend that you use camlidl for a new project.
>
> Now to answer your question: the following should work
>
> ```
> quote(C, "#include <lib.h>")
> quote(C, "void t_final (t * x) { destroy_opaque_struct (*x); }")
>
> typedef [abstract,finalize(t_final)] struct opaque_struct * t;
> ```
>
> Assuming lib.h contains
>
> ```
> typedef struct opaque_struct opaque_struct;
> opaque_struct * create_opaque_struct;
> int do_x_with_opaque_struct(int, opaque_struct *);
> void destroy_opaque_struct(opaque_struct *);
> ```
>
> The confusing thing is that `typedef opaque_struct * t` is rejected
>   because CamlIDL doesn't know about type `opaque_struct`.  However it
>   has no problems with unknown structs...